# A better way to download pdf in android?

Tags: android, pdf

I was using this code to download a pdf file from server but it is taking a hell lot of time in that the file is around 3 GB .Is there any other way to solve this problem? please help

```
  FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);

          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*10000];
          int len1 = 0;
          while ( (len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
              f.write(buffer,0, len1);
      }

          f.close();

        OutputStream outStream = null;
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        outStream.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) apis to download any files. Android will download the file for you